# There is an embedding of the Mobius strip in $\mathbb{R}^3$, what is it?

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, mobius-band

Let $M= S^1 \times ]0,1[$. Define the Mobius strip to be $N:= M/ \mathbb{Z}_2$ where the non trivial element of $\mathbb{Z}_2$ acts on $M$ by sending $(x,r) \in M$ to $(-x,-r) \in M$. I red that the manifold $N$ can be embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3$ what is this embedding? (I mean what is the function $f: N \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ which is an embedding of $N$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ ?)

Comment: Have you ever made a Mobius strip out of paper? That will actually give you a pretty good idea of how to embed $N$ into $\mathbb{R}^3$. (HINT: draw the "median line" on the physical mobius strip, and note that it's more-or-less a circle of "large" radius compared to the width of the strip itself.)

Comment: An embedding is described in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_strip#Constructions)